# What are prerequisites to automate building of C# and Powershell API based project developed using Visual studio

Tags: c#, powershell, nant, nantcontrib

I am writing an SCVMM like VMM management agent to install it as a service on Windows server 2008 R2 only.

The agent is already been developed on Windows server 2008 R2 platform using .Net 4.0 framework, C#, VMM api, Visual studio. It just runs as service. System Center tools as also been installed to work with SCVMM.

I have used NANT and NantContrib to automate the build on development machine. But I want to automate build process of the agent on actual build machine where environment is Windows7 and some Java related JRE installed.

My question is, to automate the agent, Do I need to install on build server? .Net 4.0 is enough or Do I have install Windows System Center tools as well?

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

Only if System Center Tools is required to **build** the solution. By the sounds of it from your question, System Center Tools is only required to install it. So I guess it depends if you're doing a pure build server or striving for continuous delivery..

If the build server will just generate an installer package and dump it to a file share somewhere, you shouldn't need to install any management tools on the build server. However if you also want to build server to automate deployment, these extra management tools might need to be available to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The project refers few of the libraries like Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.dll, System.Management.Automation.dll, \Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll, etc. libraries. I assume these libraries comes along with System Center tools like SCVMM, Configuration etc. The agent tartget machine must be Windows Server 2008 R2 only. But my build server Windows 7. There the required libraries might not be available. My build server build an EXE and places it on a shared location.

Comment: I see, would it be possible to bundle those required .dll assemblies into your source code repository? The compiler just needs to be able to access them when it's building the manifest for your app, it doesn't need to run System Center Tools...

Comment: I don't know if I can bundle the assemblies, those assemblies are supplied by System center.

Comment: How do you mean supplied? Does System Centre install them into the GAC when it's installed? I think it should still be possible to copy/paste them into your repository & build without having a full installation..